# How to remove the web browser default application?

Tags: unity, system-settings, default-browser

In the Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Control Center, i.e.

System Settings -> Details -> Default Applications -> Web

how can the association to any installed web browser be completely removed?

The intended result being that any URL-link-reference from any other desktop application (e.g. Thunderbird) will fail and not cause any web access.

(Yes, I know that there are more places/things to take care of to achieve this, but this question is specifically about the Unity Control Center.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is  to either rename or delete

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/webbrowser-app.desktop
```